# Spawning a Shared Worker in a Dedicated Worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm playing around with WebWorkers. Somehow I had the idea to let the different instances of a page know when another one is closed. Therefore I wrote a Shared Worker and it works fine.

But now I want a Dedicated Worker to act as an interface to the Shared Worker. So that expensive actions in the UI won't affect the continous communication with the Shared Worker.
But I get the error, SharedWorker was not defined. An idea would be to use MessageChannel, but I want it to run at least in Firefox and Chrome and as far I know, Firefox still doesn't have a working implementation of MessageChannel.

So - are there any workarounds for this problem?

Comment: you can use `storage` events to talk from one tab to all other tabs on the same domain, works "everywhere"

Comment: Why is the communication with the shared worker continuous? And why would the communication from the UI to the dedicated worker not be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create a shared worker object in the dedicated worker. However, you can create a shared worker in the main UI thread and pass its port to the dedicated worker, so they can communicate directly.

As an example, in main thread create both workers, and transfer the `port` object of the shared to the dedicated:

```
var sharedWorker = new SharedWorker("worker-shared.js");
sharedWorker.port.start();

var dedicatedWorker = new Worker("worker-dedicated.js");
dedicatedWorker.postMessage({sharedWorkerPort: sharedWorker.port}, [sharedWorker.port]);
```

In the shared worker you can post messages on this port:

```
self.onconnect = function(e) {
  var port = e.ports[0];

  self.setInterval(function() {
    port.postMessage('sent from shared worker');
  }, 1000);
};
```

And in the dedicated you can react to them

```
self.onmessage = function(e) {
  var sharedWorkerPort = e.data.sharedWorkerPort;
  sharedWorkerPort.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('received in dedicated worker', e.data);
  };
};
```

You can see this working at http://plnkr.co/edit/ljWnL7iMiCMtL92lPIAm?p=preview